# ionic2 assign value and increment valuein ion-list

Tags: angular, ionic2

i need to assign and increment value in class name in ionic2.
Below i have code. class="styles{{}}" need to increment the i value. how to assign i variable and increment that value.

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items" >
  <ion-card  ion-card (click)="successpage(item.title);" class="styles{{ i + 1 }}">
    <div class="card-title">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">{{ item.count }} Quotes</div> 
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: what `i` value should be, it should be current `index` of list?

Comment: no its not index value. need to set static looping

Comment: i need assing i value and increment that value eg. i=0; i; i++;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `let i = index;` to your `*ngFor` to iterate the no of items.

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" >
  <ion-card  ion-card (click)="successpage(item.title);" class="'styles{{ i + 1 }}">
    <div class="card-title">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">{{ item.count }} Quotes</div> 
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: how to set condition if i=10; then i value need to reset as i=1;